# How to send sms to multiple people you have a history with using URL launcher flutter

Tags: android, flutter, sms, url-launcher

I am using following code:

```
          //Sms phone number
      String num1='123';
      String num2='456';
      String msg='Hello world';

      final sms = Uri.parse('sms:${num1},${num2}?body=${msg}');
      if (await canLaunchUrl(sms)) {
        await launchUrl(sms);
      } else {
        throw 'Could not launch $sms';
      }
```

This will send a `msg` to the numbers 123 & 456.
However if one of these numbers is already in my contacts or I've previously texted them this will open up my chat with them and only send the `msg` to this number and therefore cancel out sending the `msg` to the other recipient.

So basically I cannot send to multiple recipients if I already have a history with one of them.

How can I go through with the sms instead of it opening my history with one of those contacts?

Comment: And whats is your Question?

Comment: If there is a way to go through with the mms instead of having it open your history with one of the contacts? I'll edit my original post as it's not clear.

Answer (score 1):

You could use one or booth of those packages.
I would fetch all the previous send messages and iterate though so see if there is one message with an equal phone number as of my current one.

[SMS - To get the previous send Messages](https://pub.dev/packages/sms)

[Contacs Service - To get all your Contacts](https://pub.dev/packages/contacts_service)